# How to reset smart-table sorting on button click

Tags: sorting, smart-table

After table rendering by smart table, click on header and it will sort that column.

**How to reset the sorting state such as on click of some reset button?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

You can set sort predicate to undefined like this:

```
$scope.tableController.tableState().sort.predicate = undefined
```

Hope it helpful.

Comment: I'am trying the same, but i dont understand how to get the tableState... $scope.tableController is undefinend...